# Comparator circuit

Tags: comparator

I found this comparator circuit, the caption says "Self-Biased, 50% Slicer".
Does this circuit output a logic high, when the input voltage is bigger than 2.5V and a logic low, when the input voltage is lower than 2.5V?

[image]

found on page 13 of the [ACMP60x datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/609/ADCMP600_601_602-1601928.pdf).

Comment: also, this looks like it comes from an application note, which probably explains how it works, so it'd be good to see that!

Comment: I've answered the question you stated here. However, I think you meant to ask a different question, something like "how can I build a ... that does ...". Maybe look for answers for that question on here!

Answer (score 1):

> Does this circuit output a logic high, when the input voltage is bigger than 2.5V and a logic low, when the input voltage is lower than 2.5V?

No. as you can see, there's no DC connection from the input to any reference (e.g ground), so absolute potential can't matter for this circuit!

You'll find this has time-dependent behaviour when you plot the voltages at the two capacitors' sides connecting to the comparator in the same plot. To do that analysis, you'd assume (quite reasonably) that the current going into the opamp is zero, and therefore, for the analysis, you'd just need to analyse the time behaviour of the two different RC circuits.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this circuit output a logic high, when the input voltage is bigger than 2.5V and a logic low, when the input voltage is lower than 2.5V?

This data slicer relies on the transmission protocol to set the voltage in the capacitors. For instance, if the transmission begins with a train of equal high and low pulses, the voltage in the inverting cap will settle to the average of the high and low voltages.

The Manchester protocol is especially amenable to this technique since it can be AC coupled and it spends equal times at its high and low levels.

Source: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-decode-manchester-encoded-data-using-hardware/